# Instagram API - created_time Time Zone

Tags: instagram-api

What's the time zone being used for created_time on Instagram post?

I need to know to work out the time for date range.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`created_time` is in UNIX timestamp, which is in UTC. If you want to find the timezone, you will most likely need to use the location (in latitude and longitude) of the image. That said, the image must have a location property saved to it.